# Auto submit form cannot show up the selection option properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Problem with form selection box.

I am working on a form and I try to make it auto-submit once I choose the option.

I have the following codes:

```
    <script>
    function target_popup(form) 
    { w = window.open('', 'metas_pop', 'width=600,height=400, resizable, scrollbars');
    form.target = 'metas_pop'; w.focus(); }
    </script>
    <script src="gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="osce_style.css">
```

and in the form:

```
     <form action="" method="post">
     <select style="color: red; font-size: larger" name='examiner_role' onchange='this.form.submit()' onselect='<?php $examiner_role=$_POST['examiner_role'];?>
      <option style="color: red; font-size: larger" value="1">Examiner 1</option>
      <option style="color: red; font-size: larger" value="2">Examiner 2</option>
      <option style="color: red; font-size: larger" value="3">Examiner 3</option>
      </select>
      <noscript><input type="submit" value="Send"></noscript>
```

The selection box works with the options availble. I can select the option with the correct value store into expected variable $examiner_role.
However, everytime I choose the option, the box automatically goes back to first line of the options. How I can make it stays and show the option I chooes?

Answer (score 0):

You are `submitting` the form `onchange` of dropdown so the page `refreshes` and `option` goes back to the `first one`.

Remove `onchange` event from `dropdown` because you have a separate `submit button`.

```
<select style="color: red; font-size: larger" name='examiner_role' onselect='<?php $examiner_role=$_POST['examiner_role'];?>
```

Just remove `onchange='this.form.submit()'`

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the onchange statement. Yes, the option stays but now I cannot get the value into the variable $examiner_role.  Anything I did wrong?

Comment: You can store value in `onchange` event directly. like this `onchange ='<?php $examiner_role= $('select[name=examiner_role]').val() ?>`

Comment: I don't know exact syntax how to set value in php varialbe from javascript so if there is any mistake please ignore.

Comment: I have tried but not working. I just want to keep store the selected value into a variable that I can use it elsewhere and keep the selection box.

Comment: I have tried onchange but it doesn't help. May be I use it wrongly.

Comment: The option I selected stays but the value is not store. Does the form really submitted?

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
       <select style="color: red; font-size: larger" name='examiner_role'     onselect='<?php $examiner_role=$_POST['examiner_role'];?>'>
       <option style="color: red; font-size: larger" value="1">Examiner 1</option>
        <option style="color: red; font-size: larger" value="2">Examiner 2</option>
        <option style="color: red; font-size: larger" value="3">Examiner 3</option>
           </select>
          <noscript><input type="submit" value="Send"></noscript>

           </form>